# Plotly-Dash stacked bar charts side by side responsive to a dropdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I have the following data-frame:

-- dcc.Dropdown for selecting the issue goes here on the page --

```
Job  Tenure  Location  Topic
CSM   3-5    England   Budget cuts 
CSM   6-10   Scotland  Budget cuts
SA    0-2    India     Time consuming demands
SA    3-5    England   Lack of oversight
SA    6-10   Germany   Lack of support
MIA   11-15  India     Lack of support
ADCS  20+    England   Bureaucracy
MIA   16-20  Ireland   Bureaucracy
ADCS  20+    USA       Budget cuts
```

The final outcome needs to have three sets of charts. Each set consisting of two bar charts that are stacked and side by side.

Here's what the outcome would look like:

Graph one consisting of two bars side by side:

bar 1 = stacked jobs (height=9, stack consists of 2xCSM, 3xSA, 2xMIA, 2xADCS)

bar2 = breakdown of issue by role. e.g. if  the issue "budget cuts" is selected in the dropdown, this graph will be height=3, stack consists of 2xCSM, 1xADCS.

Bar 2 needs to update when you select an issue from the drop-down. So if I now select issue 'Lack of oversight', bar 2 will have a height of 1 stacked by job 1 x SA.

Graphs 2 and 3 will be the same as above but for Tenure and Location respectively instead of job. So the stacks will be Tenure/Location in all instances where it was Job in the above instance.

To be honest even if someone can show me how to do the first chart I may be able to replicate the code for chart 2 and 3. I hope this makes sense.

Here is the output I get. I basically want these two bars on the same axis not separate like here (ignore height values as my df is larger than what I gave here).

[image]

Thanks guys.

Comment: Take a loot at https://plot.ly/python/subplots/

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple working example, adapted from

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [5, 2, 6], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF', 'xaxis': 'x2',},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal', 'yaxis': 'y2',},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization',
                'xaxis': {'domain':[0, 0.5]},
                'xaxis2': {'domain':[0.6, 1]},
                'yaxis2': {'anchor': 'x2'}
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

It should output something like,

[image]

Comment: @user8322222 I'm just curious. Did this suggestion solve your challenges?

Comment: Yes, finally got something which worked for me. Thanks a lot